# Prefetch related row or nothing with DBIx::Class, maybe with OUTER LEFT JOIN?

Tags: sql, perl, join, dbix-class

I want to retrieve rows from a table with [`DBIx::Class`](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBIx::Class) and prefetch respective rows from the same table where a column has a particular other value. I need to fetch all assignments from schedule A (to copy them) and retrieve all respective assignments from schedule B.

I have made up tables for testing which look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE tasks (
    id INTEGER
);

CREATE TABLE schedules (
    id INTEGER
);

CREATE TABLE assignments (
    id INTEGER,
    scheduleId INTEGER,
    taskId INTEGER,
    worker TEXT,
    FOREIGN KEY (scheduleId) REFERENCES schedules(id),
    FOREIGN KEY (taskId) REFERENCES tasks(id)
);
```

There are some assignments for schedule 1, and a few for schedule 2:

```
INSERT INTO tasks (id) VALUES (1);
INSERT INTO tasks (id) VALUES (2);
INSERT INTO schedules (id) VALUES (1);
INSERT INTO schedules (id) VALUES (2);
INSERT INTO assignments (id,scheduleId,taskId,worker) VALUES (1,1,1,"Alice");
INSERT INTO assignments (id,scheduleId,taskId,worker) VALUES (2,1,2,"Bob");
INSERT INTO assignments (id,scheduleId,taskId,worker) VALUES (3,2,1,"Charly");
```

This is some SQL that returns the desired result:

```
SELECT * FROM assignments AS a1
LEFT OUTER JOIN assignments AS a2 ON
    a2.scheduleId = 2 AND
    a2.taskId = a1.taskId
WHERE a1.scheduleId = 1;
```

In SQLite this works as expected: The results shows a line for each assignment from schedule 1 and the respective assignment from schedule 2.

```
id|scheduleId|taskId|worker|id|scheduleId|taskId|worker
1|1|1|Alice|3|2|1|Charly
1|1|2|Bob|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL
```

What I've tried with DBIx::Class so far doesn't work. This is what the class for assignments looks like:

```
package MyApp::Schema::Result::Assignment;

...

__PACKAGE__->has_many(
    inAllSchedules => 'MyApp::Schema::Result::Assignment',
    {
        'foreign.taskId' => 'self.taskId',
    }
);
```

The following code correctly joins the rows but returns only rows from schedule 1 which actually have a respective row from schedule 2:

```
my $assignments = $schema->resultset('Assignment')->search({
    'inAllSchedules.scheduleId' => 2,
}, {
    prefetch => 'inAllSchedules',
});
```

This code correctly also correclty joins the rows and returns rows with no joined row, too, but I don't know how to filter the joined rows. I do not want to retrieve rows for schedule 3 etc. or just *any* other row ...

```
my $assignments = $schema->resultset('Assignment')->search(undef, {
    join_type => 'left outer',
    prefetch => 'inAllSchedules',
});
```

I can not write a specific relationship because the ID of schedule A or B is only given at runtime, of course.

**How to either generate the given SQL code or otherwise retrieve the data in a clean way?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like a case for [custom join conditions](http://search.cpan.org/dist/DBIx-Class/lib/DBIx/Class/Relationship/Base.pm#Custom_join_conditions). The solution below works for your limited example, but may need tweaking for your actual application.

```
__PACKAGE__->has_many(
    'inAllSchedules' => "MyApp::Schema::Result::Assignment",
    sub {
        my $args = shift;

        return {
            "$args->{foreign_alias}.taskId" => { '-ident' => "$args->{self_alias}.taskId" },
            "$args->{foreign_alias}.id" => { '<>' => { '-ident' => "$args->{self_alias}.id" } },
        };
    }
);
```

You would use it like so:

```
my $assignments = $schema->resultset("Assignment")->search({
    'me.scheduleId'             => 1,
    'inAllSchedules.scheduleId' => [ 2, undef ],
},
{
   'prefetch' => "inAllSchedules",
});
```

Comment: Your answer looks simple and promising but that doesn't work. Comparing the ID to `NULL` seems to imply the existence of a row. The created SQL reads like `SELECT me.*, inAllSchedules.* FROM assignments me LEFT JOIN assignments inAllSchedules ON inAllSchedules.taskId = me.taskId WHERE ( ( ( inAllSchedules.scheduleId IS NULL OR inAllSchedules.scheduleId = 2 ) AND me.scheduleId = 1 ) )`. Adding `join_type => "left outer"` didn't make a difference.

Comment: Ok, I've marked your answer as accepted because it just works. Also I learned about `-ident`. Two questions: 1. Is the simple syntax `self.column_name` and `foreign.column_name` not valid when returning ON-clauses from a coderef? Why does DBIx::Class place the query arguments in the ON-clause? Actually the condition is defined like before. I don't see what exactly makes the difference and I'd like to understand. Could you please explain that?